# How to pause music while playing video in Keynote?

Tags: macos, keynote

I am currently using the newest version of keynote and have run into a major issue. I am playing audio throughout the entire presentation but i would like to add videos into the presentation.

When i export the videos in and play the presentation, the music plays while the video plays as well! Is there a way to pause the music on those specific slides?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to use Automator:

Automator -> create Service -> add applescript block

```
tell application "iTunes"   
    if player state is playing then
        pause
    else
        play
    end if
end tell
```

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services -> check the new workflow and bind it to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Afaik it's Keynote playing the music as well as the videos? The question makes no reference to iTunes?

Comment: That's very true.